# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device,but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! while working on google colab, GPU is used

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm having the following error while training my CNN model on Google Colab

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper__cudnn_batch_norm)

```py
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
    since = time.time()

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        #loss.retain_grad()
                        #loss.requires_grad = True
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

            print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
                phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
                #print(best_model_wts)
        print()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
        time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model
  
   # device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
```

```py
model_conv = train_model(model_conv, criterion, optimizer,
                         exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=2)
```

Comment: unfortunately i can't run it on my device to help you more but you need to add every tensor in your code into the `to(device)` for example the `.max` and `.sum` any tensor variable must be added into the `device`

Comment: Have you called `model.to(device)` before starting the training?

Comment: @RabeeQasem I added every tensor into to(device), but the code is still not working.@aretor yes, model.to(device) was called before setting optimizer function.

Comment: I found out that problem with the Resnet network that I have used as the first layer in my model by utilizing transfer learning technique. Now how to change that model's device type.